# Embedded python interpreter, generate stub source code for autocompletion

Tags: python, mocking

I have an application that embeds python and exposes its internal object model as python objects/classes.

For autocompletion/scripting purposes I'd like to extract a mock of the inernal object model, containing the doc tags, structure, functions, etc so I can use it as library source for the IDE autocompletion.

Does someone know of a library, or has some code snippet that could be used to dump those classes to source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [dir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) or [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) function to get the list of what has been defined yet. Then, to filter and browse your classes use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module

Example toto.py:

```
class Example(object):
    """class docstring"""

    def hello(self):
        """hello doctring"""
        pass
```

Example browse.py:

```
import inspect
import toto

for name, value in inspect.getmembers(toto):
    # First ignore python defined variables
    if name.startswith('__'):
        continue

    # Now only browse classes
    if not inspect.isclass(value):
        continue
    print "Found class %s with doctring \"%s\"" % (name, inspect.getdoc(value))

    # Only browse functions in the current class
    for sub_name, sub_value in inspect.getmembers(value):
        if not inspect.ismethod(sub_value):
            continue
        print "  Found method %s with docstring \"%s\"" % \
            (sub_name, inspect.getdoc(sub_value))
```

python browse.py:

```
Found class Example with doctring "class docstring"
  Found method hello with docstring "hello doctring"
```

Also, that doesn't really answer your question, but if you're writing a sort of IDE, you can also use the [ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) module to parse python source files and get information about them

Comment: That's all I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Python data structures are mutable (see [What is a monkey patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching)), so extracting a mock would not be enough. You could instead ask the interpreter for possible autocompletion strings dynamically using [the `dir()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).

Comment: In this case a mock would be enough. I cannot ask the interpreter because it's compiled into the executable, but I can make it execute a script to dump the internal classes.

Comment: @RamonPoca, I don't understand you. Even if the interpreter is embedded and compiled, it is still the interpreter. Please clarify your question, maybe with some code samples.

Comment: Plus presumably if the user can access the interpreter, so can the application?